# 「予定調和」 usage in casual speech

Tags: usage

What does 「予定調和」 mean? Not that stuff about Leibniz, but in daily chatter.

Comment: Why do you expect 予定調和 to be used in daily chatter?

Comment: Are you referring to sense 2 here? http://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/leaf/jn2/228010/m0u/

Comment: @snailboat I would think so. I have noticed this phrase coming up far more often in Japanese media than I would expect the phrase "pre-established harmony" (its EDICT translation) to occur in English media. It feels like either: it is more familiar a concept to Japanese audiences; or they use a complex term with a more basic meaning, where we might use a simpler phrase.

Comment: From a visual novel, when talking about how nothing unexpected can happen when playing with dolls because you control everything: 「人の世において、予定調和ほど退屈なものはない。だから、ぬいぐるみは世界で一番のお友達でありながらも、いつかは飽き、卒業する...」 Maybe in English we'd just say "Nothing in the human world is as boring as the status quo"? "as everything going according to plan"? Referencing the term "pre-established harmony" seems to me like something an English writer wouldn't do very often.

Answer (score 4):

I think very few Japanese people recognize that 予定調和 is from Leibniz (I didn't know that). When this appears in daily conversations, it means "safe but expected result", "without surprise/trouble", "never changing", "repeated many times", "according to the scenario", etc.

Typically this is used for long-running TV series like サザエさん, where characters never get old for decades.

It may have some negative nuance. If you see 「国際会議は予定調和で終わった」 in a newspaper, it probably implies the meeting was boring and unimportant.